# Ansible - How do I use an ansible_fact deeply embedded?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I can't seem to access a deepely embedded ansible_fact with this string:

```
hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_devices']['sda']['partitions']['sda2']['holders'] }}
```

Here's part of the fact tree that I'm trying to reference.

```
 "ansible_devices": {
            "sda": {
                "holders": [],
                "host": "RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID                                                                                                                                                              SAS-3 3108 [Invader] (rev 02)",
                "partitions": {
                    "sda1": {
                        "holders": [],
                        "sectors": "614400",
                        "sectorsize": 512,
                        "size": "300.00 MB",
                        "start": "2048",
                    },
                    "sda2": {
                        "holders": [
                            "root-root",
                            "root-swap",
                            "root-home",
                            "root-opt",
                            "root-tmpl",
                            "root-usr",
                            "root-var"
                        ],
```

How would I go about checking for the partition "root-home"?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a list, use index of wanted field:

`hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_devices']['sda']['partitions']['sda2']['holders'][2]`

or
 `hostvars.inventory_hostname.ansible_devices.sda.partitions.sda2.holders[2]`

My suggestion to try **jq** command:

```
ansible -m setup -l your_hostgroup | sed '1c {' | jq '.|keyes'
```